# Sharepoint connection with Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, sharepoint, oauth-2.0

i am trying to connect sharepoint with Python 3.7 have tried out a couple of ways (both illustrated below), but i encounter the same error. I do not understand where the issue lies? is it that i do not have the required access and i should request additional access from my company?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Try 1:**

```
 from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
 from office365.runtime.client_request import ClientRequest
 from office365.runtime.utilities.request_options import RequestOptions

 user_credentials = {    'username' : 'username@domain.com',
 'password' : 'my_password'}

 site_url = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com"
 ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)
 ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(user_credentials['username'], user_credentials['password'])
```

**Try 2:**

```
 sharepointUsername = "username@domain.com"
 sharepointPassword = "my_password"

 website = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com"
 authcookie = Office365(website, username=sharepointUsername, 
 password=sharepointPassword).GetCookies()
```

**Try 3:**

```
 import sharepy
 import json

 user = "username@domain.com"
 password = "my_password"

 s = sharepy.connect("https://mycompany.sharepoint.com", user, password)
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is not caused by the code. The authentication request has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. You may need to contact your Administrator to get more help.

BR

Comment: Yes, i think the same. Thanks for the confirmation!